# Разделить генерируемый PDF на листы

Tags: node.js, pdf, phantomjs

Есть задача преобразовать html страницу в удобный для распечатывания отчет в формате PDF.
Пробую использовать для этого библиотеку phantomjs.

Формирую тестовый pdf:

```
const page = await phantom.createPage();

await page.property('viewportSize', {
    format: 'A4',
    orientation: 'portrait',
    margin: {
        top: '1cm',
        left: '1,6cm',
        right: '1,6cm',
        bottom: '1cm'
    }
});
await page.property('content', '<style>h1 {color:blue;}</style><h1>Hello word</h1><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><h1>Hello word</h1>');

await page.render('test.pdf');
```

В итоге генерируется pdf файл с одним листом шириной как А4, но очень длинный/высокий.

Есть ли способ сгенерировать pdf файл таким образом, чтобы он сразу был разбит на необходимое (в зависимости от содержания) количество листов А4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно было выполнить дополнительную настройку

```
await page.property('paperSize', {
    format: 'A4',
    orientation: 'portrait'
});
```

классный инструмент